# sw_urdf_explorer for 32bit Windows

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has there been a version of sw_urdf_explorer tested for 32bit versions of Windows yet? I know that this might be a possibility but the documentation says that it's only been tested on 64bit (and I see that it won't even install on 32bit machines).
Currently the machine I'm on is a 32bit Windows 7 machine... and it will take a very long time for IT to upgrade to 64bit (if they will allow it at all).
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66330/sw_urdf_explorer-for-32bit-windows/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-07-04**:
If you tag your question correctly, you might attract the attention from more people in-the-know.

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-07-05**:
The title field isn't included? I'll update that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not that I know of. I seem to remember Stephen Brawner (the author) explaining at ROSCon'13 that it's mostly because of a math library he's using. IIRC there isn't a 32bit version of it (or he can't use it).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-07-05**:
Ok. I guess that makes sense. Thanks for the heads up.